# React - Initializing values in Redux-Form leads to multiple warning messages

Tags: reactjs, redux, initialization, redux-form

In my React (ver 17.0.2) application, I am trying to, in my functional component, initialize my Redux-form (ver 8.3.7) with values from my Redux (ver 4.1.1) store.

Here is a simplistic version of my code, where I pull the `user` object from my Redux store (`user` has a `fullName` field containing the user's full name):

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'


let Name = ({handleSubmit}) => {
    return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}> 
                <label>Full Name</label>
                <Field name="fullName" component="input" type="text" placeholder="Please enter your full name..." />
            </form>
    );
};

Name = reduxForm({
    form: 'nameForm',
    enableReinitialize: true
})(Name);

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        initialValues: state.user
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Name);
```

The code does work, in that it initializes my input box with the user's full name, but I get multiple errors such as:

```
Warning: Using UNSAFE_componentWillMount in strict mode is not recommended and may indicate bugs in your code. See https://reactjs.org/link/unsafe-component-lifecycles for details.

Move code with side effects to componentDidMount, and set initial state in the constructor.

Please update the following components: Form(Name)
```

appearing in my console.

Looking online, it seems I have done it as recommended and I can't figure out what I should be doing differently / maybe use a completely different library.

What is the correct way to do this / what should I change so as to remove these warnings (hopefully without resorting to changing the source-code for Redux-form which I have seen some online answers point to doing)?

Comment: https://github.com/redux-form/redux-form/issues/4721 - The last comment here is about rewriting the "unsafe" methods. Since it's not your code, and they seem to be aware of it, I'd just ignore it, or contribute to the repo yourself to address the issues.

Comment: Thanks, @BrianThompson, I was afraid the only solution was that - I'm just SO new to React / Redux, I don't feel comfortable yet changing source-code. I guess ignoring it is the best course of action for now. Unless you have any other idea about how I can get my form initialized / updated values stored??

Comment: The warning is just that, a warning. It should not have any affect on how your code operates. However, the main page of the redux form docs encourage new users/projects to not use the library. So the best course of action may be to use something else

Comment: I COMPLETELY missed the warning not to use Redux-Form anymore - Thank you so much for mentioning it! - I'm just starting with it, so `react-final-form` it'll be!! - Thank you, @BrianThompson !!

Comment: PS - @BrianThompson, if you'd like to just summarize the idea of ignoring the warnings or moving to react-final-form and posting it as an answer, I'll happily accept it.